# Downloading YouTube videos via a Python script

Tags: python, linux, youtube, youtube-dl

I am trying to use [this script](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/documentation.html) to download YouTube videos using Python.

Currently I use this as follows

```
youtube-dl "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvsdgyuv"
```

In the documentation they have written that I can use these

```
id: The sequence will be replaced by the video identifier.
url: The sequence will be replaced by the video URL.
uploader: The sequence will be replaced by the nickname of the person who uploaded the video.
upload_date: The sequence will be replaced by the upload date in YYYYMMDD format.
title: The sequence will be replaced by the literal video title.
stitle: The sequence will be replaced by a simplified video title, restricted to alphanumeric characters and dashes.
ext: The sequence will be replaced by the appropriate extension (like flv or mp4).
epoch: The sequence will be replaced by the Unix epoch when creating the file.
autonumber: The sequence will be replaced by a five-digit number that will be increased with each download, starting at zero.`enter code here`
```

They have not written how can I use that.

How can I use to have the video file name same as title?

They told to use this, but I don't know how to use this on the command line.

```
%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the bottom of the documentation, it says how:

> The **-o option allows users to
>   indicate a template for the output
>   file names**. The basic usage is not
>   to set any template arguments when
>   downloading a single file, like in
>   youtube-dl -o funny_video.flv
>   "http://some/video". However, it may
>   contain special sequences that will be
>   replaced when downloading each video.
>   **The special sequences have the format %(NAME)s**. To clarify, that's
>   a percent symbol followed by a name in
>   parenthesis, followed by a lowercase
>   S. Allowed names are: ...

You run the command like this to use those special output parameters:

```
youtube-dl "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvsdgyuv" -o "%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s."
```

Comment: thanks for that , i didn't used double quotes in that string before. Also is it possible to download in different folders. i mean first crate the folder then download in it

Comment: In Linux, you just run `mkdir foo` and set `-o` to `foo/%(title)...`

Comment: Actually i was thinking of making script which automatically gathers playlists from youtube and downloads playlists in specific folders. i think i need to call mkdir before calling this script for playlist

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is http://np1.github.io/pafy/. It rocks, 100%!

Answer (score 0):

With a Python script:

```
import youtube_dl

youtube_playlist_url = 'youtube_playlist_url'
destination_folder = './youtube_playlist/'

ydl_opts = {'outtmpl': destination_folder+'/%(title)s.%(ext)s'}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([youtube_playlist_url])
```

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mn0zj8Ql7Fs